# PHP replace $this-> with something shorter?

Tags: verbose

Can anyone think of some sort of preprocessing or something that could be put in place to reduce this horrible verbosity?

Typing `$this->` constantly is driving me insane, why can't it just be achieved with a different symbol from $; $ for normal scoping £ for `$this->` scoping.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use static class? I have a static helper class named H and each time I need it I simple type in H::function(params) ...

Comment: static class can be good looking. :)

Comment: A static class is not a one stop solution to the inconvenience  @Shammoo is dealing with. You are assuming his not dealing with class instances.

Comment: No, I'm building a proper program (stupidly) in php. I need proper OO.

Comment: I've deleted your answer from the question, since you have (correctly) supplied that as an answer. You may have been downvoted because the question seems to be based on a dubious proposition - it does not seem to me to be hard work to type `$this->`, and even that can be added as an editor shortcut if necessary. (FWIW, I have not voted).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I added the answer to the body because I cannot accept the answer for another day. So this question remains open and it is an absolute magnet for downvotes. I keep it open because it is actually important and highlights a fundamental issue with the language. Someone has to eat the downvotes to share this information with the world. Although it's a pain, I will do it for the world.

Comment: To quickly expand on the issues as I see them. PHP was clearly originally designed to do simple things in a simple way. It was designed to render webpages programmatically. So in version 5.6, it is still the case that easy things are easy and can be achieved with simple and clean syntax. The expense here is the more advanced the structure and the more removed from the original intention, the more verbose your code becomes, because all the simple syntax is used by simple cases. The result is the harder the solution is to cognize, by virtue of being large, the the harder it is to read.

Comment: I have edited again, since we do not use title hacks like [solved] and [answered], nor are they necessary in the body either. I have (reluctantly) removed the `php` tag for now, though this means it will need editing again to put it back. It _is_ a PHP question and it needs that tag - I will try to replace it in a day or two, after you have accepted your answer.

Comment: Your edit remarks make it seem that you wish to close the question; it may just be easier for you to delete it - I believe that it is possible. I doubt anyone will take the question/answer as evidence that PHP is too verbose though - that there is "a fundamental issue" with the language would be contended by most users, in my opinion. FWIW though, I can't imagine it attracting more downvotes.

Comment: (Mark for future editing).

Comment: Thank you, @halfer

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not really possible. Unless you create your own version of PHP and change the interpreter (Which I strongly recommend against for numerous reasons).

Also changing `$this->` to your own thing would hurt your code compatibility greatly. Especially if someone were to work on your code in the future.

If you really have a hard time dealing with this, I strongly recommend you install a IDE like PHPStorm or any other IDE with auto completion or setup your own macro to type it out for you.

Comment: I suppose I would expect that. It is a shame there are no frameworks or anything of the like that deal with this. It's a good and versatile language, but it really forces me to write code that looks like spaghetti.

Comment: @Shammoo What looks like spaghetti code to someone is different for everyone ofcourse. But coding standards like PSR2 (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). Really helps if you are having trouble about formatting of the code you write. As a added bonus everyone who needs to work with your code can work with that standard.

Comment: I conform to PSR2, the code that php forces is just verbose and rubbishy; especially if you're trying to maintain standards like dependency injection etc...

Answer (score -1):

Sed to the rescue! Here's my code for condensing some of the verbosity.

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Running server
for f in ./src/*.php
do
    sed -f ./preprocess.sed $f > ./live/`basename $f`
done

cd live
php ./server.php
```

preprocess.sed

```
s/£/$this->/g
```

#### Before / After

```
    case TableState::INIT:
        $this->gone->reset($this->tableSpot, $this->tableNote);
        $this->state = TableState::WAITING;
        break;
```

And after

```
    case TableState::INIT:
        £gone->reset(£tableSpot, £tableNote);
        £state = TableState::WAITING;
        break;
```

As everyone else has said, this makes your code not functional be default, so you need to do sufficient documentation around how preprocess. But I think `sed -f ../preprocessor.sed ./*` in the source directory will make it all normal code.

Comment: Hmm, that's less keystrokes for you, but less readable for other devs who need to touch your code. And any modern IDEs will throw all manner of syntax warnings (NetBeans, Eclipse, PHPStorm, etc), making it harder to spot unintentional errors.

Comment: Yeah, the user will have to define the extended syntax in the IDE. I know this sometimes is not an easy thing to do. I obviously wouldn't recommend this for large shared code bases. It is essentially just for medium standalone projects when you need the code a bit more manageable.

Comment: Also, it isn't about key strokes. It's about readability. $this-> 3 times in a line makes it much harder to translate what is going on. Another advantage is I run into far fewer errors this way. It is easier to notice the different between a $ and £, than it is to identify the missing $this-> .